# The verb "to get" + particle ...?

Tags: verbs, particles, predicate-adjectives

In the phrase "to get all crazy" am I correct when I say that the "all crazy" is a particle phrase? Example:

> I'm up for tonight's party. I'm going to get **all crazy**.

Comment: I believe you mean *participial phrase*.

Comment: It's not a participial phrase, either.

Answer (score 4):

It is not a particle phrase.  A [particle phrase](http://www.kuleuven-kortrijk.be/nl/Onderzoek/Letteren/OnderzoekTaalkunde/FEST/DescriptiveEnglishGrammar/bert-cappelle/Complex%20particle%20phrases%20in%20English.pdf) is a phrase consisting of the [particle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_particle) associated with the [phrasal verb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verb), the particle's modifiers (if any), and (though [some](http://www.kuleuven-kortrijk.be/nl/Onderzoek/Letteren/OnderzoekTaalkunde/FEST/DescriptiveEnglishGrammar/bert-cappelle/Complex%20particle%20phrases%20in%20English.pdf) do not include this) the [direct object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_%28grammar%29):

> He pulled **off the sticker**. (Or, as some define it: *He pulled **off** the sticker*, or *He pulled the sticker **right off***)

In your example, *I* is the [subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_%28grammar%29), *[am going to](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Going-to_future)* is an idiomatic verb phrase describing the future tense, *get* is the [copula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_%28linguistics%29) (or *linking verb*), and *all crazy* would be called the *[predicate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_%28grammar%29)* or *subject complement*, and specifically a *predicate-adjective phrase*.

Answer (score 2):

**Get** is a linking verb here, as it means **become**. So the phrase **all crazy** is a *complement*, a phrase that describes the subject of the verb.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know the term *particle phrase*, I’m afraid. In the sentence ‘I'm going to get all crazy’, *get* acts as a copulative verb. The structure is much the same as ‘I'm going to be all crazy.’ 'All crazy' is the *complement* of 'get', but you may also know it as *subject predicative*.

Answer (score 2):

*Get* has two major semantic uses in English, and any number of idiomatic ones. Semantically, *get* is an Inchoative (change-of-state) verb; in particular, it is the inchoative form of **both** *be* and *have*.

- *He is cold now, but he was not cold before; he **got/became** cold.*
- *He has a cold now, but he did not have a cold before; he **got** a cold.*

*Become* is an inchoative form of *be* (it's derived from *come to be*) and therefore can substitute for *get* when it means *come to be*, but it **can't** substitute for *get* when it means *come to have*.

- **He **became** a cold.*

Thus, *get all crazy* is **not** a phrasal verb, and *all crazy* therefore can't be a particle phrase. It's just an ordinary predicate adjective phrase (with *all* as an emphasizer instead of *very*).

> (Parenthetically, this fact is the genesis of *I have = I have got = I've got = I got*, which we're all familiar with, not to mention *hafta = have to = have got to = got to = gotta*, and various [*got ~ gotten* usages](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/gotten.html)).