# What meaning of "get" is in the "get paid" phrase?

Tags: grammar, verbs

*Get* has a lot of meanings in English, but which one is used in phrase *get paid*? *Get* is often used for describing a change of state, similarly to *become*. But does *get paid* fall into this case? From what I know, when used with the verb in ING/ED state it means "begin with". Considering the change of state, should I think of it as that a person who gets paid is "becoming paid", and also his state changes to "paid" when he possesses the money?
An additional question: My textbook says that GET + adjective expresses the change of state but I think it also applies to <s>ppt</s> past participle of verbs, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[In the words](http://rapgenius.com/Bob-dylan-subterranean-homesick-blues-lyrics#note-8598) of noted Minnesota folk grammarian [Robert Zimmerman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Dylan):

> Get sick, get well, hang around the inkwell
>   Get jailed, jump bail, join the Army if you fail
>   Get born, keep warm, short pants, romance
>   Learn to dance, get dressed, get blessed, try to be a success.

These are all examples of "change of state". The examples using **get** above follow the same pattern as your own "get paid".

To wit, **get** here just means ***become***.

Answer (score 12):

This is the so-called ***Get* Passive**, which works exactly the same as [the ***Be* Passive**](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/570173/15299), except that different forms of *get* are used instead of *be*.

- *I was paid yesterday. ~ I got paid yesterday.*
- *They were married last month. ~ They got married last month.*
- *This video was seen by millions. ~ This video got seen by millions.*

There is occasionally a minor distinction between the two constructions, in that the *Get* Passive can imply more responsibility by the agent than the *Be* Passive.

One difference between

- *Bill **was** arrested by the campus police last night.*

and

- *Bill **got** arrested by the campus police last night.*

is that the speaker of the second example, with *got*, may be implying that Bill was not blameless in the arrest. There is even an idiomatic construction

- *Bill **went and got arrested** by the campus police last night.*

which definitely implies that Bill did it on purpose.

Comment: #John Lawler Would you say that in many of these examples get has a causative function?

Comment: _Get_ is the [inchoative/causative form](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/51355/15299) of [**both** _be_ and _have_](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/104219/15299), so it normally has such a meaning. This is what's responsible for the small difference between _He was arrested_ and _He got arrested_; the first one says nothing about his involvement, but the second has a cancellable invited inference that he was responsible in part for the event. The inference is even stronger in [_He got himself arrested_.](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/83013/15299)