# "There is to be no drinking beer today" What is the status of "no" and "beer" here?

Tags: grammar, verbs, nouns, parts-of-speech, objects

1. There's no doubting her sincerity.
2. There's no telling what she's done.
3. There's no guessing which way they'll bolt.
4. There's to be no drinking beer today.
5. There's no telling her.

The word *no* is usually thought of as a determinative. We expect to see it in Determiner position in noun phrases. Of course, we often see determinatives in Determiner function with deverbal nouns:

- **The** reading of books is prohibited.
- This constituted **a** breaking of his silence on this topic.

Notice that because the *-ing* forms above are nouns and not verbs, they cannot take direct objects and the phrases after them are preposition phrases. If we omit the word *of* the sentences are ungrammatical:

- ***The** reading  books is prohibited. (ungrammatical)
- *This constituted **a** breaking  his silence on this topic. (ungrammatical)

My questions  therefore are:

- What part of speech is the word *no* in examples 1-4?
- How should we regard the syntactic function/grammatical relations of the word *no* in relation to the phrases it occurs in?
- What is the syntactic function of the strings after the *-ing* forms. (direct object /complement?)
- What part of speech are these *-ing* forms?

Comment: What part of speech is *no* in "There's to be no water here today"? Is that not the same as 1-4?

Comment: I have no idea of the name, but as a hint, I think 'The reading of books' is a noun phrase in itself. So you're not modifying a single-word gerund like 'reading' here - you're using a four-word noun phrase. Does that simplify things?

Comment: I don't know if it's my dialect, but I could put *of* in those sentences easily: There is to be no drinking of beer today. There's no doubting of her sincerity. There's no telling of what she's done. The only weird one is the last "There's no telling of her." That doesn't sound right.

Comment: @KitZ.Fox That's interesting. For me (British Eng) "drinking of beer" is the only vaguely acceptable one.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Well, there's loads of reason to say just that. But then that would make *no* a determinative in Determiner function. Then that would make *telling* in 5, or *drinking* in 5 a noun. That should mean that these *-ing* forms can't take objects. They would need an *of* or some other preposition before the next noun phrase.

Answer (score 7):

I'd say that 1-4 are hybrid constructions where "no" is a determinative functioning as a determiner in construction with a gerund-participial VP head.

In 1. and 4. the post head NPs are objects, but in in 2. and 3. the post-head dependents are not NPs but interrogative complement clauses where 2. means *There’s no telling the answer to the question* "*what has she done*”? and 3. means *There’s no guessing the answer to the question* "*which way will they bolt*"?

I called them 'hybrid' constructions because the pre-head dependents are characteristic of NP structure while the post-head ones are characteristic of VP structure. They are virtually restricted to the existential construction with “there”.

Comment: Does the fact that 2 and 3 are not NPs mean they are not objects in this instance? We can have PP objects etc. If they aren't objects, what is their syntactic function  do you think? I don't think being an object = being an NP.  I'd understand "complement clause" for a catenative complement, for example, but I'm not sure about these instances ( ; (Oh, +1, btw).

Comment: I can't see them at all as objects. As 'open' interrogatives, I'd say their syntactic function is complement of the verbs concerned, hence 'interrogative complement clause'.

Comment: Hmmm. (Devil's advocating here) You can have clauses as Subject right? So why not Objects?Complement Clause sounds a bit like an underdefined Complement in general ...

Comment: (I don't disagree with you btw, just couldn't explain in a good way why I do, which is why I'm trying to get you to tell me why I should!)

Comment: Non-finite clauses are only objects when they occur in some distinctively object relation with some element other than the head verb, for example in the complex-transitive construction: _This made drinking beer virtually impossible_. In other instances, they're usually catenatives, as you mentioned, but here they are clearly interrogatives with no structural or semantic resemblance to objects.

Answer (score 2):

These are two idioms involving *There*-Insertion. (1-3) are examples of one idiom, (4-5) of another.

- *There's no `Vcog`-ing* means 'No one can `Vcog`', where
  `Vcog` is a cognitive verb (*doubt, tell, guess*) 
  that is the VP of a gerund complement clause.
  I.e, the NP following *no* in this idiom (which is an NPI, by the way) is parseable as

  - `[np [s [vp Vcog`*-ing*  ... `vp] s] np]`
    which means that the *no* is an ordinary determiner of the complement NP in this idiom.
- The other idiom is

  - *There's no* `Vvol`*ing*, which means '`Vvol`*ing* is impossible/not customary/not allowed';
    `Vvol` is a volitional (hence forbiddable) activity, requiring a sapient agent subject.
    With additional syntactic gymnastics like Neg-Raising the idiom can appear as either
  - *There's not to be* `Vvol`*ing*
    or as
  - *There's to be no* `Vvol`*ing*
    which both mean '`Vvol`*ing* is forbidden' only.  As these last two examples demonstrate,
    the *no* in *There's to be no drinking beer* is also an NP determiner, and one which is coreferential with the adverbial *not* of *There's not to be drinking beer*.

Note that there is at least one modal **and** one negative involved in each of these constructions, plus obligatory  *There*-Insertion, and idiomaticity all over the place. This produces odd-looking syntax.

As for the specific questions, *no* is an NP determiner, as noted, modifying the outer NP of the complement clause; the various `V`*-ing* are all gerunds, the VPs of gerund complement clauses. Since they're `V`s, they can have objects and all the rest, and that's what *beer* is, for instance.

Comment: +1 Thank you very much. Does this not perhaps undermine the idea that in "The killing was uncalled for" the word "killing" is a noun ( to be devil's advocatey  about it).

Comment: Of course it is. If it takes a definite article, it's a noun.

Comment: Btw Vcog=cognitive verb. Whats Vvol?

Comment: Right! So that's what's puzzling me. "No" is a determiner too (and not a possessive one), which would make one think that *doubting* was a noun too ... no?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Volitional. I.e, deontic interpretation, indicating 'forbidden' in this negative idiom.

Comment: _Doubting_ in that S is a V, but it's bracketed [np [s [vp [v] vp] s] np], and the outer/upper NP is the node to which _no_ is adjoined. The last 2 Ss distinguish the adverb and the determiner, even though they're coreferential.

Comment: OK, I'll need to read that slowly and  cogitate for some time. Thanks.

Comment: Here's another one to cogitate on. _He's going to put some old questions on the exam, but which ones isn't clear_ is grammatical; *_but which ones aren't clear_ is ungrammatical. _Ones_ is clearly plural, _is_ is clearly not, but that's what's called for. And if you can get a copy, look at McCawley's "On identifying the remains of deceased clauses".

Comment: Already did, I thought.

Comment: "He's going to put some old questions on the exam, but which ones isn't clear is grammatical; *but which ones aren't clear is ungrammatical" <-- That's because *which ones* is a kinda deceased interrogative clause, no?

Comment: You got it. Fossilized Ss can turn up as NPs.

Answer (score 1):

Taking your questions out of order:

> What part of speech are these -*ing* forms.

They are examples of the [*gerund*](http://www.grammaring.com/the-forms-of-the-gerund) -- a verb form that functions as a noun.  Note well the distinction between "*functions as* a noun" and "*is* a noun," as this bears directly on your question.  Gerunds are verb forms, but there are also "verbal nouns", which often have the same lexicographic form as gerunds, but are *bona fide* nouns.

> What is the syntactic function of the noun phrases after the -*ing* forms. (direct object /complement?)

[Gerunds can be combined with objects or adverbials](http://www.grammaring.com/the-use-of-the-gerund), whereas verbal nouns cannot.  The noun phrases in question are objects of the gerunds.

The reason that your example "The reading books is prohibited" is ungrammatical is that gerunds *do not* take determiners, so one of the following must hold:

- "reading" is interpreted as a gerund, and the presence of "the" is erroneous, or
- "reading" is interpreted as a verbal noun, in which case it cannot have an object and the presence of two consecutive nouns is erroneous, or
- "reading" is interpreted as a participle modifying books, and plural "books" does not agree in number with "is".

Whichever you choose, the sentence is erroneous.

Now consider these alternatives:

- "Reading books is prohibited."  This sentence can be understood only by interpreting "reading" as a gerund, with "books" as its object, because you cannot have two consecutive, independent nouns there, and, as already observed, "books" does not agree in number with "is".  It is thus *reading* that is prohibited, at least when it is books that are read.
- "The reading of books is prohibited."  This sentence can be understood only by interpreting "reading" as a verbal noun.  As a verbal form, gerunds do not take prepositional phrases or determiners, but like any other noun, verbal nouns can accept both.  This has the same meaning as the previous sentence, but different grammatical form.
- "Reading books are prohibited."  This sentence can be understood only by interpreting "reading" as a participle modifying "books", because as a gerund or a verbal noun, singular "reading" does not agree in number with "are".  It is thus certain *books* that are prohibited -- reading books, but not necessarily coloring books.

> what part of speech is the word *no* in examples 1-4?

"No" can be used as a determiner, an adverb, or a noun (at least; [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/no)).  These particular constructions are rather idiomatic, which may be why they are troubling you, but I classify the "no" in each of them as an adverb modifying the gerund.

> how should we regard the syntactic function/grammatical relations of the word *no* in relation to the phrases it occurs in.

What?

Comment: Thanks. Hmmm. "*The reason that your example "The reading books is prohibited" is ungrammatical is that therein "reading" will be understood as a participle modifying books (not a gerund), and plural "books" does not agree in number with "is". Consider, on the other hand, "Reading books is prohibited", wherein "reading" is again a gerund, with "books" as its object.*" <-- But *why*can't we just understand "the reading books" as a gerund? After all it has a determiner which is what we expect from nouns (and you think gerunds are nouns). So why is it not acceptable as a noun?

Comment: @Araucaria, you have inspired me to re-think and revise my answer.  The general thrust remains the same, but some of the key particulars differ, especially where your question comes to bear.