# Questions about "get" and "be"

Tags: be, get-passive

Is it good English to write the following passive sentences, considering that it should describe what a system is doing in general (but maybe not necessarily at the moment)? I am interested in the word "get", whether it is appropriate in these situations:

- Text **gets** analysed [by the system].
- Files **get** stored [by the system].
- Data **gets** displayed [by the system].

---

Furthermore, I would like to know whether the following sentences are good English, when "get" is used instead of "be", considering that it should describe what a system is requiring in general:

- The button needs to **get** pressed [in case of this and that].
- Users can **get** added [to the system].

If yes or no, why or why not?

Comment: [The _Get_-passive is perfectly grammatical](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/67009/15299). There are some minor differences from the _Be_-passive, but not many. BTW, this is American English; with UK Englishes, your mileage may vary.

Comment: British English wouldn't normally use the last two.