# How to use "be" and "get"?

Tags: grammar

I was reading an article and I found **be** and **get** being used at two places.

Extract-

Different workers respond to this in different ways and some employees may **be left behind**

there is a risk that others who are more comfortable being managed may **get left behind**

What is the difference between **be left behind** and **get left behind** . Also, I thought of other two lines where I am confused with **get** and **be** .

**When they were being shot**

**when they were getting shot**

What is difference between meanings of the two lines ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What meaning of "get" is in the "get paid" phrase?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67006/what-meaning-of-get-is-in-the-get-paid-phrase) (John Lawler's answer)

Comment: So if I say "he was getting rude" it means he was becoming a rude person. And "he was being rude" means he was acting as rude. Is it correct ? @Edwin Ashworth

Comment: Both mean his behavior was changing toward rudeness. _Get `Adjective`_ means 'become more `Adjective`'.

Comment: 'He was getting rude' means 'he was beginning to use rude language (/gestures ...)'. 
 'He was being rude' means 'he was using rude language ...'.